# Filter directory list text file based on the short common root directory

Tags: sort, filter

I have a list of directories similar to the below in a .txt file

```
/Season_1/101
/Season_1/101/Thumbnails
/Season_1/101/Thumbnails/Branded
/Season_1/101/massive_screengrabs
/Season_1/102/massive_screengrab
/Season_1/102/thumbnails
/Season_1/102/thumbnails/Branded
/Season_1/103/Thumbnails
/ARCHIVE/480x360 v6/Season 2
/ARCHIVE/480x360 v6/Season 3
/ARCHIVE/480x360 v6/Season 4
```

I'm looking for a way to filter out directories based on the shortest common root directory when compared to the rest of the list. The results would look like the below.

```
/Season_1/101
/Season_1/102/massive_screengrab
/Season_1/102/thumbnails
/Season_1/103/Thumbnails
/ARCHIVE/480x360 v6/Season 2
/ARCHIVE/480x360 v6/Season 3
/ARCHIVE/480x360 v6/Season 4
```

Another need for this is to be compatible with all sorts of randomly named directories so anything that would use a string like "/Season_1/101" to solve this specific example would not work as the directories could be named anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will work with text files that do not contain blank lines. If you need to accommodate blank lines some modification would be required.

`cat textfile | sort | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/" }; { if ( NR == 1 || $0 !~ lastField ) { print $0; lastField = $NF } }' > newtextfile`

Where `textfile` is your text file and `newtextfile` is where you want to output the results to. You can omit `> newtextfile` if you want to see the results on standard output.

The file is first sorted to set it up for awk to iterate record by record, starting with the shortest version of any similar lines. Awk determines if the last part of a given record is contained within the next line. It only outputs lines which don't have the duplication.

Comment: I think this just solved it!! Thanks so much. This is going to save me hours and hours and hours of time.